# location of long running postgres backup

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I am taking a postgres backup in Windows, db size is around 250GB:

`pg_dump.exe -h $PGHOST -U postgres -Fc -b -v -f $dumpfile -Z 9 $DB 2> $logfile`

$dumpfile and $logfile are both showing 0KB. I'm not sure what is happening in the background. The backup has been running for over 10 hours.

How can I make this faster?
Are files being generated in a temporary location right now? Where is that temporary location?

Comment: How are you checking the size?  File Explorer often shows zero size for files created by a redirect and still being written to, even when they are clearly not zero size.

Comment: pg_dump acquires an wek (access share, I think) lock on all tables before it starts dumping them.  You can use pg_stat_activity and pg_locks to see if it has gotten blocked on a lock.

Comment: DB Size: SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_database_size('dbname') );

Comment: That would not show the size of the progressing backup.  Unless you are writing it to the data directory, which is a bad idea.

Comment: The backup finished in 32 hours. It was around 130 GB in the end, while the DB size was around 250 GB. Perhaps there is no fast/parallel ways to do this.